# Subversive install in Eclipse not showing any option to commit or checkout

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

[image]

I am using ADT to develop Android application in Linux Mint. Because of the backup and restore of the source code I thought of using SVN in Eclipse, so I went to

> Subversive - http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x through the "install new software" and install.

This shows me two option

> Core SVNKit Library (required)
>     Optional JNA Library (recommended)

Which I installed now I am confused how to checkout my code from my repository or commit my code to it. I don't see any option to do it.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/faq.php\

Comment: right click your project Team->Share Project...

Comment: okay could you please let me know the entire procedure?

Comment: @PadmaKumar when I click on Team---> Share Project I get a window which shows options however its for GIT I think. I am attaching the screenshot. Please see this.

Comment: @PadmaKumar Thanks bro now I can see that option for SVN too. Now I can check in and check out. Thanks for showing me the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, SVNKit is the connector (client) to connect your SVN, with installing it you can checkout,commit or update your codes.

As far as i know JNA is a little library for native access to shared libraries to make things easier. From wiki:

```
Java Native Access provides Java programs easy access to native shared libraries
without using the Java Native Interface. JNA's design aims to provide native access in 
a natural way with a minimum of effort. No boilerplate or generated glue code is
required.
```

So i think you should install both, but JNA is optional as FAQ says :)